# Crystal Reports dynamic parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports 2020, I have a dynamic parameter. Since there can be 100000's of values, the user does not want to scroll through all of them,but wants an option to enter the value in a search box (like when we set Static parameter) and then add it to Selected Values box.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant portion of a KnowledgeBase Article:
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1381361

SAP Knowledge Base Article - Public

1381361 - Dynamic Parameter List of Values are displayed in batches in Crystal Reports and in SAP BI LaunchPad
Symptom
How to change the batch size?
Crystal Reports dynamic prompt list of values are displayed in blocks of values. How to change the number of values per block?
Dynamic Parameter Lists of Values are displayed in a list of pages, is there any way to change the number of values displayed per page?
When refreshing a report in Crystal Reports, or in SAP BI LaunchPad, Dynamic Parameter shows the List of values in batches, how to display the List of Values in one single list instead of multiple groups?
Environment
SAP Crystal Reports 2013
SAP Crystal Reports 2016
SAP Crystal Reports 2020

SAP BusinessObjects Business Intelligence Platform 4.1
SAP BusinessObjects Business Intelligence Platform 4.2
SAP BusinessObjects Business Intelligence Platform 4.3
Reproducing the Issue
In Crystal Reports designer, create a report off any data source.
Create a a Dynamic Parameter, and add it to the report.
Save the report to the SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise Repository.
Refresh the report in Crystal Reports, or in SAP BI LaunchPad.

When prompted by the parameter, notice that not all values displayed in one list, it displays in multiple batch.
How to only show one list with all the values?
Cause
Large list of values for dynamic parameter are displayed in batch of 200 values.
Resolution
There is no option to turn off the functionality of displaying dynamic parameter list of values in batch, but it is possible to increase the number of values per batch by modifying the following options:

- For Crystal Reports: PromptingLOVBatchSize
- For the SAP BusinessObjects Business Intelligence Platform: crystal_max_number_list_of_values

Therefore, to display all the values in one batch, increase the value of the batch to be greater than the maximum number of values you expect for your largest list of values.

WARNING The following resolution involves editing the Microsoft Registry. Using the Microsoft Registry Editor incorrectly can cause serious problems. Use the Microsoft Registry Editor at your own risk. For more information see the SAP Knowledge Base Article 1323322

For Crystal Reports designer:
Close the Crystal Reports designer.

Open the Microsoft Registry Editor. ( regedit )

In the Microsoft Registry Editor, navigate to the following path:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\ReportView

Modify the value for the option: PromptingLOVBatchSize from the default value of 200, to a greater value like: 5000